# NPE attempting to read tabular data in cucumber-jvm (cucumber-clojure)

Tags: clojure, cucumber

In my feature file I have something like this:

```
  Scenario: Things
    Given the table is empty
    When I add a thing:
      |          Foo  |    Bar |      Baz |
      | 1293883200000 | 123.45 |   123456 |
      | 1293884100000 | 123.45 |   123456 |
```

Any ideas? Doing it wrong? Bug in cucumber-jvm?

It matches my step definition, but before actually executing the code inside of it, I get a null pointer exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.getGenericListType(StepDefinitionMatch.java:144)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.tableArgument(StepDefinitionMatch.java:135)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.transformedArgs(StepDefinitionMatch.java:103)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:43)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:220)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:32)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:101)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:92)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:30)
    at leiningen.cucumber.util$run_cucumber_BANG_.invoke(util.clj:48)
    at user$eval43.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
    at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:315)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:348)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:405)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
    at ✽.When I add a thing:(api.feature:9)
```

Comment: could you include your cucumber version from project.clj? and a bit more context

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'm using lein-cucumber, which is using info.cukes/cucumber-clojure version "1.0.0.RC13"

Comment: It's using a cucumber-clojure that is not the latest, so just to be certain that the version was not the problem, just now I created a version of lein-cucumber using RC20, installed into my local maven, and used that in my project. I still get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug in `cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch` where the [code that deals with tabular data](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/StepDefinitionMatch.java#L136) calls `getGenericListType(int)`, which in turn dereferences `StepDefinition#getParameterTypes()`.

Unfortunately, `cucumber.runtime.clojure.ClojureStepDefinition#getParameterTypes()` [always returns](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/clojure/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/clojure/ClojureStepDefinition.java#L44) `null`, thus resulting in the NPE.

I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/250) pointing to this question.

Comment: Thank you for doing the work of digging down into the Java to figure this out! :)

Comment: I've sent a pull request with a bug fix. In the meantime, you can use https://github.com/nilswloka/cucumber-jvm/tree/table-data-for-clojure-stepdefs.